# How to get date using sqldf?

Tags: r, date, sqldf

I have a data frame that has a "DATE" field. e.g.: `"24-10-2015"`

The variable is in the date format.

When I use *sqldf*, e.g.: `select min(DATE), MAX (DATE) from table ...` the output is a number like `16623`.

Tried *FORMAT* and *CONVERT* but they don't work in sqldf.

Any hints?

Comment: SO creates long-term usable information for current & future readers.
Questions should be self-contained with the minimal code & data needed so readers can copy it from the question & paste it into a running R session & see what the poster sees.  The data should be part of the question & not elsewhere to ensure that it continues to be vailable.  Use the R command `dput(X)` to provide X in reproducible form.  See (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (2)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (3) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify the methods for each column in the data frame. Assume 'data' is the name of the data frame with the column name 'd' containing the 'Date' format.

Try the following:

```
sqldf('select max(d) as MAX__Date,
              min(d) as MIN__DATE
       from data',
      method = "name__class")
```

This should work.

Comment: This was my preferable method, since no changes are made on the data of the data frame. And IT WORKS!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you transform your date to `POSIXct` using `as.POSIXct` so that you can work with the `date` function of `SQLite`:

Using some random data:

```
#notice I keep the class of the date as POSIXct
#it really does not change anything
df <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct('2015-01-01'))

#> df
#        date
#1 2015-01-01
```

And then you can do:

```
#using the date function in SQLite you convert the nanoseconds
#produced by min(date) back to a date.
sqldf('select date(min(date), "unixepoch", "localtime") from df')
  date(min(date), "unixepoch", "localtime")
1                                2015-01-01
```

And you have what you need. There is more info about how SQLite understands dates [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: An other solution is to use `as.Date(16623)` which will return "2015-07-07"

Comment: Thanks @etienne . How do you mean?

Comment: When saxo runs his code the output are numbers so after his code he can convert the numbers into dates using `as.Date(number)` which will return a Date.

Comment: @etienne I see. So, you mean after running the `sqldf` function. This is a possibility for sure. You still need to provide the `origin` argument in order to work but you are right. You may want to write it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

An other possibility is to not change your `sqldf` function and then to convert your dates stored as numbers. You can use `as.Date()` for this :

```
zoo::as.Date(16623)
[1] "2015-07-07"
```

As LyzandeR mentioned, you should specify an `origin` which states what the first date is. If you are using the `zoo` package, the default is "1970-01-01" and for your format it is probably the correct origin, but if you don't use it (meaning you sue the function from the `base` package then you must specify it.

```
as.Date(16623, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2015-07-07"
```

But if you had dates from Excel you should change the origin :

```
zoo::as.Date(42313)
[1] "2085-11-06"

as.Date(42313, origin = "1899-12-30") # for Windows, use "1904-01-01" for Mac
[1] "2015-11-05" # correct result
```

I actually found why not supplying `origin` was working for me : I had the package `zoo` loaded, in which "1970-01-01" is the default option for `origin`:

```
base::as.Date(16623)
Error in as.Date.numeric(16623) : 'origin' must be supplied

zoo::as.Date(16623)
[1] "2015-07-07"
```

Here are the codes where you can see that `zoo` specifies a default `origin` for the function `as.Date.numeric` which is not the case for the `base` package :

```
base::as.Date.numeric
function (x, origin, ...) 
{
    if (missing(origin)) 
        stop("'origin' must be supplied")
    as.Date(origin, ...) + x
}
<bytecode: 0x17190e78>
<environment: namespace:base>

zoo::as.Date.numeric
function (x, origin, ...) 
{
    if (missing(origin)) 
        origin <- "1970-01-01"
    if (identical(origin, "0000-00-00")) 
        origin <- as.Date("0000-01-01", ...) - 1
    as.Date(origin, ...) + x
}
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

Comment: Good one! On my computer `as.Date(16623)` returns an error: `'origin' must be supplied` . This is probably a < R 3.2 error.

Comment: @LyzandeR: I don't know why it works on my computer as I have R 3.0.2 But in the help it is written "as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch), but only if origin is supplied." so the best practice is to include the origin

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check specific date values and not date ranges, you could convert your date column into a string using as.character before you call your sql code, like so:

```
table$date2 = as.character(table$date)
sqldf("select max(date2), min(date2) from table")
```

This worked really well for me and I haven't run into any drawbacks yet.

from:
https://ladvien.com/sqldf-dates/